# Do Cocoa Pods Re-Install When Uploading To App Store?

Tags: swift, cocoapods

So I'm using a library that's been abandoned but I've made quite a few changes within its files under Pods. If the pods are reinstalled, the library won't work. What's the best practice for this sort of thing?

I have forked the project over and updated it with my changes.

Instead of having the line:
pod "PodToIntall"

I have 
pod "PodToInstall", git: => "the url to my fork", branch: => "master"

If I try to pod install I get the error

```
[!] Unable to find a specification for 'PodToInstall'
```

The project is dead so if I can't get the owner to merge my changes is there any way to pull it off my github?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proper way of editing a CocoaPod Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40948995/proper-way-of-editing-a-cocoapod-library)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that all steps are done from the following list:

1. Change the source files from your forked pod project.
2. Commit it & push to GitHub (if pod is hosted here).
3. Update the Podfile within your main project to use forked pod.
4. Run in terminal `pod update PodToInstall`.

Also [CocoaPods and GitHub forks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20936885/cocoapods-and-github-forks) might be useful.